# How to use search in DataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) to draw my data. Also I am using OData filter to show only those rows which I need, by several conditions.

```
var dtApi = new $.fn.dataTable.Api("#CardsGrid_grid");
...
filter assing (for example: "Status eq 0" and...)
...
dtApi.draw();
```

It works fine. I am receiving what I need. 
Now I need to find and show only those rows whose value contains a value from a textbox.

So, according to [this link](http://datatables.net/reference/option/searching), `column().search(value)` should do the thing, and this supposed to look like:

```
var search = $("#searchInTable").val();
dtApi.column().search(search).draw();
```

but the thing is that this does nothing. At all.
I assume that I am doing it wrong. Or, maybe because I am using OData (and as a result, `dtApi.rows().filter` also not reaction on anything).

How can I use search correctly?

Comment: Could you please clarify the phrase: "and as a result, dtApi.rows().filter also not reaction on anything"?

Comment: Its the same situation as with column().search(). Simply does nothing.